# How Sign out from firebase with dialog

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-dialog

I am trying to signout user from my app.

**What can i do so far ?**

I am able to sign out the user on a button click

**What i want ?**

When the user press the sign out button i want to pop up dialog which ask user if he is sure about it ,then from the positive button i want to sign out, and then start the Login activity

**What is the problem?**

In the click listener of the dialog's positive button i wrote the code for signing out , but as the singing out code is asynchronous and the dialog was immediately closed on press of positive button , so when the sign out `onComplete()` runs the dialog is not there because it is already closed so i get the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment SignOutDialog{fef4a91 (b8bfbb8c-cdff-4244-9952-81516d1ed736)} not attached to Activity
```

**This is the code**

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
     return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle(R.string.sign_out)
            .setMessage(R.string.sure_sign_out)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    signOut();
                }
            }).create();
}

private void signOut(){
  AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(mContext)
          .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                  if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                      Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,MainActivity.class);
                      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                      startActivity(intent);
                  }
                  else
                      Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Sign out failed, try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
          });
}
```

**What other approaches i tried**

**1**  *I tried writing signout code after showing the dialog in the same fragment which hosts the dialog*

Something like

```
public void onClick(View v) {
           new SignOutDialog(getActivity()).show(getFragmentManager(),"tag");
           signOut();
          }
```

But problem in that is dialog is also asynchronous , so after showing the dialog signout code executes and the user does not gets a chance to press the positive button of dialog.

**2**  *I tried writing the signout method in the fragment where  the  code for showing the dialog is and then tried to call that method from the singleton instance of fragment from the inside dialog, because that fragment will be attached when the dialog close so i will not get the error above*

something like

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    SettingsFragment.getInstance().signOut();
                    }
```

But that approach gives me the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Null context is not permitted.
```

i did not understand that error because in `signOut(context)`  am using same context i got in `onAttach()` i also tried `getActivity()` , `getContext()` and `getConext().getApplicationContext()` and fragment is in foreground the context should be valid but it says it is null.
Even if it works somehow i don't want to use that approach because it is not very clean.

**May somebody please help me please ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a `DialogFragment`, when your dialog dies, it also dies the `DialogFragment` and since the `DialogFragment` dies it will not be attached to your activity, that is why you have this problem

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment SignOutDialog{fef4a91
>   (b8bfbb8c-cdff-4244-9952-81516d1ed736)} not attached to Activity

Keep it simple, don't use a DialogFragment, just use a normal Fragment and create your dialog when you want to launch it after a button press that says `SignOut`

```
btn_signout.setOnClickListner { ...
    AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(R.string.sign_out)
                .setMessage(R.string.sure_sign_out)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        signOut();
                    }
                }).create().show();
}
```

If you want to dismiss this dialog after the signout is completed, create this as an instance of AlertDialog, build it inside the button and then use that alertdialog to dismiss it in the completion of the signout

Comment: THANKS your solution works, i appreciate that , and i would also like to know is there any way to make it work with dialog fragment , so that it can survive the rotations , and also can you please tell the reason for the error in the approach 2 , which is mentioned in the question, i am just curious to know

Comment: The problem there is not the context of the SignOut method, but instead of the DialogFragment, when your dialog dies (is dismissed) the Fragment that inflates that dialog also dies, when you try to acces the context of the fragment in your SignOut method with getContext() it cant be reached because the Fragment has died (onDestroy()) has been invoked and also your Fragment is detached from your activity.

Comment: why the setttingsFragment(which inflates dialog) dies with SignoutDialogFrament it doesn't happens with my other dialog fragments, and can't the solution work somehow with dialog fragment

Comment: When you extend from DialogFragment, the dialog is inflated in the context of the DialogFragment and not the context of the SettingsFragment, you are calling your signout inside the DialogFragment and doing that , when your dialog dies, the Signout method lost its context, use your DialogFragment just to show, dismiss and create your dialog, do not put logic there, instead, you can have your signout method in your SeetingsFragment and just launch the dialog there from the DialogFragment, when the DialogFragment dies, the SignOut method will have the context of the SettingsFragment

Comment: DialogFragment is intended to build custom dialogs that are reusable in different Fragments, you can also use the Builder pattern there and keep a DialogFragment to instantiate different dialogs in your Fragments

Comment: I have a video (spanish) on how to use the Builder pattern to build custom dialogs extending from DialogFragment, you can adapt the kotlin code to your java use case, but at the end, is the same https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_fG8HRIiB4&t

Comment: can you add english subtitles?, as you know english you can also dub it in the english

Comment: I will be trying to add to the videos the english subtitle, its a lots of videos for now I dont have really the time, but you can see the code, you will understand it I'm sure